# How should I use "No Action Needed" while reviewing in "Physics.SE"?

Tags: support, review

We've got this new option called "No Action needed". I think this got rid of two things. I've got no evidence. But, *I think*...

1) **Skip:** I use this when I don't know what the post actually means. For example, I hate to look in [quantum-field-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-field-theory), [string-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-theory), etc. So, I usually skip those posts, except if there's some spam / *wasting-time* answers which we can easily recognize. Now, my usage of "Skip" has been drastically reduced by the introduction of this option.

2) **Upvoting:** A few months ago (before this option came into existence), I noticed that there was a *cruel upvoting* by some guys (I think, it's from some reviewers). We can notice it in the first posts. When we're reviewing, we can see that it has already been upvoted. I don't think those answers deserve an upvote. But if the upvoter believes that it deserves, then I've got another point. Whenever there's a first post, it gets upvoted. And, we can notice that while reviewing. And now, there aren't posts with so *cruel upvotes*. I had a chat with @tpg regarding that Okay, that's just a minor discussion.

I think the definition of this option doesn't satisfy me. My question is: "When do I use this option? Is there something wrong if I use it excessively?"

Does "No action needed" means - *"It needs no action from me"* (which is somewhat rude, because many posts will go like that) or as it states as a popup - *"This answer seems to be valid"*.

Both definition bugs me. Can someone point me an MSO post regarding that option, or atleast tell me,
*Is my reviewing OKAY?*

Answer (score 3):

[Been there, done that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues/161391#161391)

> ### Late Answers and First Posts
>
> [....]
>
> In these queues, you can edit the post, flag it, upvote or downvote it, add a comment, or upvote a previously existing comment.  When you take one of these actions, the **I'm Done** button becomes enabled, allowing you to complete review. If you feel that the post is fine as it is, but you don't want to vote on it (you're not *that* impressed with it, etc), then you can always click the **No Action Needed** button. If you're unsure about the post, *please* use the **Skip** button.

Comment: I love it when I get to quote myself :)

Comment: All right. Then, *I'm doing it right*. That's cool... Read the whole post ;-)